# The method firefox() is undefined for the type DesiredCapabilities

Tags: selenium, testing, firefox, methods, desiredcapabilities

I am trying to run the selenium grid in my machine and am getting the following for all the browsers at 
            cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();:
The method firefox() is undefined for the type DesiredCapabilities

Below is my code

package parallel;

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GridTest {


public WebDriver driver=null;

    @Parameters("browser") //testng.xml
    @Test()
public void googleTest(String b) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException{

    System.out.println("Google " + b);

    DesiredCapabilities cap = null;

    if(b.equals("firefox")){
        cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setBrowserName("firefox"); 
        cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
    }else if (b.equals("chrome")){
        cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
        cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
        cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
    }else if (b.equals("iexplore")){
        cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); 
        cap.setBrowserName("iexplore");
        cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    }

    try{driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.0.30.240:4446/wd/hub"),cap);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {


    driver.get("http://google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Hello "+b);
    Thread.sleep(2000);


    driver.quit();

}}}
```

Comment: You need use   Firefox::Options class .DesiredCapabilities  is deprecated in latest version of selenium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding selenium standalone server to my pom.xml fixed the issue:

```
<!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server-standalone -->
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```